# Customisation of web database template using access service in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

There are 5 types of web database templates(assets,projects,issues,contact etc) available in sharepoint by default.My requirement is using access as a service is there any way to create a custom list. Because from what i have googled itseems there will be default columns eg: in projects database template option available in sharepoint. But user wants those columns to be customised as their wish.Thanks